# how to retriving postgresql data in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i created table in **postgresql**  ,table name master it contains uid,sitename,description,user ,password as bellow

```
 uuid | sitename |    ipaddr      | descri   | username |  pswd  
 1234 | blore    | 1              | qwe      | ii       | 323232

 123  | us       | 1              | assd     | 123456   |  898

 12   | blore    |www             | a        | asa      |  34
```

and i created two **label** in  two square box in **view** ,one label releted to **blore** and one related to **us** i need help how to **count**  the  sitenametaht  contains **blore** and **us** .

if **blore** contains in **site name** two time so  i want display in lable as **blore=2**

and **us** in **sitename** one time and i display that in another  label as ****us= 1**

i need help how write and **retrieve** **sitename** in **conroller**  using ruby on rails.

Comment: Controller? View? ... ok... How about Model???? Are you trying to pull raw data out of a postgres db?

Comment: i am doing first time in postgresql ,i want retrieve directly from postgredb with out creating code in model like master.rb ,i want retrieve using query,how to retrieve data in controller

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for your table

```
class Master < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'master'
  self.primary_key = "uuid"
end
```

And now in your controller

```
@sitename_count = Master.group(:sitename).count
```

This will give you

```
{"blore" => 2, "us" => 1}
```

for the example you have given

**UPDATE:**

For direct query(Without model)

```
@sitename_count = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT sitename, COUNT(sitename) FROM master GROUP BY sitename")
```

Comment: i sir thank u for the code.but i know this way of creating in model ,but i want directly retrieve from postgresql, with out creating in model master.rb i want directly  retrieve from database using query in controller,as per my knowledge may be question is wrong  i am new to ruby onrails donot mind sir

Comment: one more question sir as per ur code in model i need retrieve data using query instead off self.tablename = 'master' and  self.primary_key = "uuid"

Comment: @user3382880: Updated my answer to use the direct query

Comment: hi sir , can u please give the view code i am getting error in view part, error:uninitialized constant P7AccessinfoController::----.